# Option to push, publish and sync greyed out in Visual Studio, works in command line

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have recently installed Visual Studio on a new machine. It is Visual Studio Professional edition, version 17.7.5 which I think is the latest. I am able to connect to all my repositories but I have found that the push/publish and sync buttons in the Git Changes panel are all greyed out. I can still make local commits through the menu but I have to use the command line to push to origin. This works just fine (`git push`) so I assume it must be an issue with how Visual Studio is set up. The repositories are in Azure Devops.

[image: Image of greyed out Git options in Visual Studio Professional 2022]

Comment: I'm currently using 17.6, and if my local branch has not been pushed yet, then I have icons for fetch and push, but not pull and sync. Once I push then all 4 icons are available. In your case it appears that you only have pull available, which does seem odd.

Comment: What does `git status` show from the command line?

Comment: Hi there, may I assume that you have connected to Azure DevOps repo via the VS `Team Explorer` to clone the repo from remote to local and the local commits cannot be pushed as the `Push` button is greyed out? Can you please navigate to `Git -> Settings -> Git Repository Settings -> Remotes` to check if the origin information includes both `Fetch` and `Push`? How is the content in the cofig file in the .git folder of your local repository like?

Comment: @TTT and Alvin Zhao - it turns out closing and reopening the solutions fixed the issue. It seems like it happens with an repo I open for the first time and connect to git. It then goes away the second time. Seems like a VS bug.